# How to install Ubuntu in Android OS, v2.3 (Gingerbread) phone?

Tags: installation, ubuntu-for-android

Can any one guide me installing Ubuntu in "Huawei U8800 Pro" which uses "Android OS, v2.3 (Gingerbread)" as the operating system? Any thoughts whether ubuntu can be installed in this phone?

Thanks in advance.

Thanks and Regards,
Gary

Comment: I would also know if this is possible and how to do it

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/258552/83046

Comment: There is a little [tutorial](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2162534) on how to flash the developer preview onto a Samsung Galaxy S+ (i9001) which uses Android 2.3 Gingerbread. Maybe it is useful for you.